# Getting linker issue with math lib

Tags: c++, cmake, linker

[image]
As you can see every possible line that set CXX have -lm included

[image]

Comment: Post text as (formatted) text please, not as images.

Comment: Did you generate the makefiles again? When you make changes to CMakeLists.txt, you also need to regenerate the build files. Delete your current build directory and run `cmake` again.

Comment: Text was formatted but still complains.

Comment: Yashas's answer worked

Answer (score 0):

Except the linker flag. You should use `target_link_library(target m)`.

Don't set the compilation flags for a linker operation, they are not propagated for good reasons. That would be `CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS` or `CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS`, but there are proper CMake commands to check that the libraries are available and that handle dependencies properly (not the case when you modify the flags directly).